# What is the best practice to handle huge number of user created events in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am totally a junior programmer in terms of database creation and structuring.

Currently, I am prototyping an application in which users can define unique events and others can join the initiated events.

To handle this situation, I have a table in which users add their own events and each event has a couple of features like name, date, unique id, location and etc.

The question is, when others want to join one specific event, is it a good practice to create a table for each event and add joined users of that event with their own ids to the created table (which in the future will result in having infinite tables) or it is better to have one table and just add all joined users to that table, then extract the information like number of joined users by counting the unique id of the event?

What is the best practice in handling these situations?

Thanks

Comment: "is it a good practice to create a table for each event" - no. Use the other one.

Comment: It's not a good practice to let user actions create new tables, new columns, etc. I called this "Metadata Tribbles" in my book [SQL Antipatterns](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns/).

Comment: While the first solution is obviously wrong, it's not obvious that the second solution is right.

Comment: @Strawberry between these two, it is :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a table Event, containing EventID and CreatedByID as a foreign key from Users table.
Create a table EventUsers containing EventID (foreign key from Event Table), UserID (foreign key from Users table) where you will find only users participating in a specific event.